# How to use javax.speech api without ide but with VS Code edittor

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, text-to-speech, speech

I am a visually impaired developer. I am new to text to speech in Java and I want to add text to speech to my project. I have checked online tutorial and all of them are talking about free TTS.
I have read so many tutorials and they are using IDE such as: IntelliJ, NetBeans and others which I don't use.

Could someone help me to set the free TTS up without these IDEs but with VS Code?

I tried importing javax.speech.Engine in my code and it gives me the below error.
code
import java.speech.Engine;
saved in Speech.java
command line

javac Speech.java
the error

Speech.java:1: error: package javax.speech does not exist
import javax.speech.Engine;

Answer (score 0):

Have you already introduced dependencies to your project? *Referenced Libraries* under the **PROJECTS** panel manages your dependencies. Add directly without build tools. If you use maven or gradle, add it in the [corresponding file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_dependency-management).

[image]

If the `javax.speec` package is not available, it may be deprecated. You can also try `Google Cloud Text-to-Speech` or `FreeTTS` packages. You can install and manage them through maven or gradle.

For example, add the following items to the *pom.xml* (using Maven)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-texttospeech</artifactId>
  <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>
```